Actualizar Widget periodicamente en android de manera asincrona
Mucho gusto, he estado tratando de hacer que mi widget en android trabaje solo, lo he logrado, pero el problema esta en que se muestra muchas veces, se actualiza muchas veces y no da margen de espera (la informacion no se queda en pantalla) a pesar de que le he configurado ciertas cosas para que no este haciendo las llamadas al api muchas veces
class ClientAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 1-----")

        val sharedPreferencesHelper = SharedPreferencesHelper(context)
        val token = sharedPreferencesHelper.getToken()

        val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ClientWorker>()
            .setInputData(Data.Builder().putString("token", token).build())
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workRequest)

        val liveData = WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.id)

        val observer = Observer<WorkInfo> { workInfo ->
            Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 1.1 -----")
            if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state.isFinished) {
                Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 1.2 -----. State: ${workInfo.state}")
                val clientNames = workInfo.outputData.getString("clientNames") ?: "No hay informacion, revisa tu conexion o inicia sesion"

                Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 1.3 -----. State: $clientNames")

                val updatePeriodMillis: Long = 6 * 60 * 1000
                for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds!!) {
                    Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 2 -----")
                    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_client)

                    Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 2.1 -----")
                    try {
                        val intent = Intent(context, ClientAppWidget::class.java)
                        intent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
                        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            context,
                            0,
                            intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                        )
                        Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 2.2 -----")

                        Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 2.21 -----" + if (Constants().isValidJson(clientNames)) Constants().formatJsonToText(clientNames) else clientNames)

                        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetText, if (Constants().isValidJson(clientNames)) Constants().formatJsonToText(clientNames) else clientNames)

                        val alarmManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

                        Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 2.3 -----")
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                            AlarmManager.RTC,
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + updatePeriodMillis,
                            updatePeriodMillis,
                            pendingIntent
                        )
                        Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 2.4 -----")
                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
                        Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 2.5 -----")
                    } catch (e: Exception){
                        Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------ON UPDATE 3 -----" + e.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        liveData.observeForever(observer)
    }
}

tambien mi clase que hace el llamado hacia el api es el siguiente

class ClientWorker (appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val clientRepository = ClientRepository(ClientApi.create())
        val token = inputData.getString("token") ?: return Result.failure()

        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------API CALL INITIATED-----")
                val response = clientRepository.getClientsByDay(token, visitDay = Constants().getCurrentDay(), days = 1)
                Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------API RESPONSE RECEIVED-----")
                if (response.success) {
                    Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------API CALL SUCCESS-----")
                    val clients = response.data ?: emptyList()
                    val gson = Gson()
                    val clientNames = gson.toJson(clients)
                    val outputData = workDataOf("clientNames" to clientNames)
                    Result.success(outputData)
                } else {
                    Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------API CALL FAILED-----")
                    Result.failure()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("--WIDGET--", "------EXCEPTION: ${e.message}-----")
                Result.failure()
            }
        }
    }
}



al hacerlo asi, se esta haciendo muchas llamadas al api, a pesar que le tengo configurado de que se tarde mas tiempo en el
alarmManager.setRepeating(
                            AlarmManager.RTC,
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + updatePeriodMillis,
                            updatePeriodMillis,
                            pendingIntent
                        )

tambien probe realizar lo con

PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder

cambiando esto
val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ClientWorker>()
            .setInputData(Data.Builder().putString("token", token).build())
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workRequest)

por esto
        val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ClientWorker>(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setInputData(workDataOf("token" to token))
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "ClientWorker",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, // Keeps the existing work if it already exists
            periodicWorkRequest
        )

el logcat se llena de informacion

Alguna sugerencia que me puedas apoyar, estoy abierto a cambios, muchas gracias

Es menos complicado de como lo estás intentando. No necesitas AlarmManager para esto, sino una combinación de PeriodicWorkRequest y Worker, pues lo que estás necesitando es un tipo de trabajo Diferible. Es esencial que conozcas todas las herramientas disponibles y elegir siempre según el caso de uso concreto la que más convenga. Te recomiendo que leas TODA la documentación al respecto. Una vez decidas la herramienta que necesitas entonces trabaja con esa herramienta.
